# Can't get Infinite Scroll working. (jQuery Plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin [Infinite-Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) with no success. My problem is that the plugin just don't work, nothing happens, even a console error and everything looks pretty fine. I need to use this one because I am going to use another plugin ([jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)) and its supports and recommends Infinite-Scroll. I get Masonry working easily, but not the Infinite-Scroll.

So I start to test Infinite-Scroll alone, in a test page, but nothing.
Any help?

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Infinite-Scroll Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #container {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .element {
        background: #666;
        width: 100px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 5px;
        float: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
            nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector : '.element',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            test
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="page-nav">
      <a href="next.html"></a>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

**next.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            new one
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```